Cuda error while rendering using 2 gpus
I am having a cuda error saying “failed to create cuda context illegal adress” I am using 4070 super and 3070 ti for rendering in cycles, it renders fine if i try to use single gpu, the error is displayed only when i use multiple gpu, the drivers for both the cards are upto date, this is the first time i am trying rendering using multiple gpu, please help

Are you overclocking either GPU?

Nope, neither of the gpu is overclocked, both are at default settings

This happens when scenes don't fit into GPU memory as well. Does your scene fit into the memory of each GPU? VRAM does not combine. Each GPU needs to have a copy of the scene.

Yes as i mentioned, it gets rendered fine when i try to render them with a single gpu, the scene is heavy, memory usage goes upto 10 gb, the 3070 ti only have 8gb of memory but when i try to render it with 3070, its renders fine and takes 7 minutes per frame, i am assuming extra 2 gb is used from system memory here, on the other hand, the 4070 super is 12 gb, takes 2 minutes to render each frame

With two RTX cards you should be using Optix
